# Problemas com inserção em uma array

Tags: javascript, angular

```js
vm.categorias = function () {
  ConectaVagas('get', 'categorias').then(function (val) {
      vm.categorias = val;
      for (var a = 0; a < vm.categorias.length; a++) {
          console.log(a); // Aqui retorna 0,1,2,3 ( Número de categorias )
          ConectaVagas('get', 'subcategoria', vm.categorias[a].id_categoria).then(function (val) { // Lista das subcategorias relacionadas a categoria acima
              vm.subAplicar = val;
              console.log(a); // Aqui retorna o número 4 porém queria que retornasse ou o 0 ou 1 ou 2 ou 3 como está acima assim me deixando eu fazer a inserção na array 
              vm.categoria[a].arrayNova = vm.subAplicar;
          });
      }
  });
}
```

Precisaria inserir no objeto vm.categoria[a] uma array ( arrayNova ) com todas as subcategorias, porém não estou ocnseguindo :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema é que `ConectaVagas` é assíncrono e por isso o `for` já acabou e deixou o `a` com o valor `4`. Tens de guardar uma referência do `a` para cada vez que chamas `ConectaVagas`. Podes fazer isso assim:

```js
vm.categorias = function() {
  ConectaVagas('get', 'categorias').then(function(val) {
    vm.categorias = val;
    for (var a = 0; a < vm.categorias.length; a++) {
      console.log(a); // Aqui retorna 0,1,2,3 ( Número de categorias )

      (function(i) { // aqui o "a" vira "i" e fica guardado para cada iteração do loop

        ConectaVagas('get', 'subcategoria', vm.categorias[i].id_categoria).then(function(val) { // Lista das subcategorias relacionadas a categoria acima
          vm.subAplicar = val;
          console.log(i); // Aqui retorna o número 4 porém queria que retornasse ou o 0 ou 1 ou 2 ou 3 como está acima assim me deixando eu fazer a inserção na array 
          vm.categoria[i].arrayNova = vm.subAplicar;
        });
      })(a);

    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Deu certo! Muito obrigado!